# Calling onload on element already loaded

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, handler

What happens if you call `onload()` on an element (e.g. iframe) which is already loaded?

Supposing `myIfram`e is already loaded, I execute this:

```
myIframe.onload = function () { console.log('iframe loaded') };
```

Will it execute?

Comment: Why don't you open the console and see if it prints? ;)

Comment: When the onload is called, how do I make sure the iframe is loaded? Depending on internet speed the iframe can take longer or shorter to load, so I don't know the status when onload is called.

Comment: First of all, that will throw an error. It should be `myIframe.onload = ...` not `myIframe.onload() = ...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I've correcte it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not a valid JavaScript syntax. Executing the code
   `myIframe.onload() = function () { console.log('iframe loaded') };`
   will cause an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

2. The onload event does not exists, but the load event does and the correct way to attach it to the HTML element is `iframe.addEventListener("load", () => console.log("iframe loaded"));`
3. Once the iframe had loaded, it will not recieve the load event again, but you can create the event manually and pass it to the element `var event = new Event("load");`  `iframe.dispatchEvent(event);`
4. Once you dispatch the load event, causing the iframe to recieve the load event two times, you will see "iframe loaded" printed twice in the console.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("frame");
  iframe.addEventListener("load", () => console.log("iframe loaded"));
  var event = new Event("load");
  iframe.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>
        Functions
    </title>

</head>
<body>
 <iframe id="frame" src="http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/corporate-gateway-guide/content/resources/images/hpp_iframe_-_paymt_mthd_select_page_04.jpg"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Penev! So that means if the iframe is already loaded by the time we execute the load event, it won't receive it? In that scenario only the second console.log will be executed (form the manually created event)?